# Variable default values

Tags: c, default-value

I'm confused about some basic theory in C programing:

1. What are the default values for variables of different datatypes? Example: If I declare as follows what may be the result according to standard C manual which is documented by legend Dr. Dennis Ritchie?

   ```
   int x;
   printf("%d",x);
   ```

   I knows that some GCC compilers will print 0 and some print garbage values. It depends on compiler. Please give me the unique answer as per Dennis Ritchie C programing documentation.

   Same as above, please give me answers for float, char, double, string, array and pointers.
2. If I declare and print pointer as follows:

   ```
   int *pt;
   printf("%d",pt);
   ```

   What will be printed on screen? I used MinGW GCCcompiler version 3.4.2, and in that I get a garbage value. Please help me in these confusions.

Thank you.

Comment: `printf("%d", pt);` has undefined behavior; `"%d"` requires an argument of type `int`. To print a pointer value: `printf("%p", (void*)pt);`

Comment: Please note that Messrs Ritchie et al have been out of the loop for quite a while. The current gold standard is ISO C. Search for it. There are plenty of sites where you can find answers to this simple question.

Answer (score 4):

The values of local (non-static) variables are indeterminate, i.e. you can't tell their values. Using an uninitialized non-static local variable leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Global variables, and static local variables, are zero initialized. Unless initialized when declared of course.

Answer (score 3):

Default values:

- Static local variables: 0
- Static global variables: 0
- Non-static global variables: 0
- Non-static local variables: none

The address of a non-static local variable in a function depends on the state of the stack (the value of the SP register) at the point in execution when the function is called.

In other words, this address is **not** constant throughout the execution of the program, and setting a default value to such variable would essentially mean adding code to the program.

So the standard does not define a default value for non-static local variables, in order to allow the programmer to choose whether or not to add this extra piece of code.

All the other types of variables **do** have constant addresses in memory throughout the execution of the program, so setting them to a default value doesn't mean adding code to the program (their initial values are essentially part of the executable image).

Comment: Global variables (with or without the static keyword) have __static storage duration__. This then means that they will be zero initialized .

Comment: @sharth: Yep, I was  just about to change that when you commented; thanks.